# Unicode generated by toEscapedUnicode method is without spaces

Tags: unicode, utf-8, escaping, space

For this word चौरेउत्तमयादव the Unicode is==>
`\u0938\u0941\u0916\u091A\u0948\u0928\u093E\u0928\u0940 \u0930\u0940\u091D\u0941\u092E\u0932 \u091C\u093F\u0935\u0924\u0930\u093E\u092E`

and look it has spaces before `\u0930` and `\u091C`

But when I am trying in my code

```
String tempString=Strings.toEscapedUnicode(strString);
```

This method to convert to Unicode gives a result without spaces:
`\u0938\u0941\u0916\u091A\u0948\u0928\u093E\u0928\u0940\u0930\u0940\u091D\u0941\u092E\u0932\u091C\u093F\u0935\u0924\u0930\u093E\u092E`

and that's why they are not matching. 
My 'toEscapeUnicode' method generates Unicode without spaces.
I want the spaces, so how to do it?

Comment: You probably need to identify the programming language you are using (the script is Devanagiri).  Did you write the 'toEscapedUnicode' function?  If so, we'll need to see it to have any chance of working out what the trouble is.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a whole answer, but...when I copy'n'paste the Unicode characters "चौरेउत्तमयादव " and then use a couple of tools to analyze what's there, I do not see any spaces:

```
echo "चौरेउत्तमयादव " | odx
```

This produces a hex dump of the data; there's a blank at the end, but none in the middle.

```
0x0000: E0 A4 9A E0 A5 8C E0 A4 B0 E0 A5 87 E0 A4 89 E0   ................
0x0010: A4 A4 E0 A5 8D E0 A4 A4 E0 A4 AE E0 A4 AF E0 A4   ................
0x0020: BE E0 A4 A6 E0 A4 B5 20 0A                        ....... .
0x0029:
```

And the second command decodes UTF-8 data:

```
echo "चौरेउत्तमयादव " | utf8-unicode
```

It produces:

```
0xE0 0xA4 0x9A = U+091A
0xE0 0xA5 0x8C = U+094C
0xE0 0xA4 0xB0 = U+0930
0xE0 0xA5 0x87 = U+0947
0xE0 0xA4 0x89 = U+0909
0xE0 0xA4 0xA4 = U+0924
0xE0 0xA5 0x8D = U+094D
0xE0 0xA4 0xA4 = U+0924
0xE0 0xA4 0xAE = U+092E
0xE0 0xA4 0xAF = U+092F
0xE0 0xA4 0xBE = U+093E
0xE0 0xA4 0xA6 = U+0926
0xE0 0xA4 0xB5 = U+0935
0x20 = U+0020
0x0A = U+000A
```

So, it seems that your problem might be with the input to 'toEscapedUnicode' rather than with its output.

---

Also, it seems that what I copy'n'paste from the question doesn't match what you say is in the string:

```
Yours     Mine

\u0938    U+091A
\u0941    U+094C
\u0916    U+0930
\u091A    U+0947
\u0948    U+0909
\u0928    U+0924
\u093E    U+094D
\u0928    U+0924
\u0940    U+092E
\u0020
\u0930    U+092F
\u0940    U+093E
\u091D    U+0926
\u0941    U+0935
\u092E
\u0932
\u0020
\u091C
\u093F
\u0935
\u0924
```

So, the pasted text does not match the claimed translation for other reasons too.

---

I believe that the Unicode string you specify should look like:

सुखचैनानी रीझुमल जिवतराम

I used a file containing the values you claimed, minus the `\u` prefixes and with 0020 in place of the blanks:

```
0938
0941
0916
091A
0948
0928
093E
0928
0940
0020
0930
0940
091D
0941
092E
0932
0020
091C
093F
0935
0924
0930
093E
092E
```

And then I used this pure home-brew Perl script to generate the UTF-8 string I propose as the equivalent of your escaped Unicode string.  I'm sure there are mechanisms available in Perl to do it otherwise (using Unicode-related modules), but this worked for me.  It would be less verbose if I didn't leave the debug code in there):

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use constant debug => 0;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    my $i = hex;
    printf STDERR "0x%04X = %4d\n", $i, $i if debug;
    if ($i < 0x100)
    {
        # 1-byte UTF-8
        printf STDERR "  0x%02X (%3d)\n", $i, $i if debug;
        printf "%c", $i;
    }
    elsif ($i < 0x800)
    {
        # 2-byte UTF-8
        my($b1) = 0xC0 | (($i >> 6) & 0xFF);
        my($b2) = 0x80 | ($i & 0x3F);
        printf STDERR "  0x%02X (%3d)\n", $b1, $b1 if debug;
        printf STDERR "  0x%02X (%3d)\n", $b2, $b2 if debug;
        printf "%c%c", $b1, $b2;
    }
    elsif ($i < 0x10000)
    {
        # 3-byte UTF-8
        my($b1) = 0xE0 | (($i >> 12) & 0xFF);
        my($b2) = 0x80 | (($i >>  6) & 0x3F);
        my($b3) = 0x80 | ( $i        & 0x3F);
        printf STDERR "  0x%02X (%3d)\n", $b1, $b1 if debug;
        printf STDERR "  0x%02X (%3d)\n", $b2, $b2 if debug;
        printf STDERR "  0x%02X (%3d)\n", $b3, $b3 if debug;
        printf "%c%c%c", $b1, $b2, $b3;
    }
    else
    {
        # 4-byte UTF-8 or error
        die "Oh bother!";
    }
}
print "\n";
```

You can fill in the 4-byte UTF-8 and error handling stuff.  I don't diagnose invalid UTF-8 sequences (notably the UTF-16 surrogates), so if you put bogus Unicode data points in, you will get bogus UTF-8 values out of the script.  If you need to know more about that, read Chapter 3 of the Unicode book (available for download - as a chapter - from [Unicode.org](http://unicode.org/)) or the [FAQ - UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 and BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Comment: may i know what tool is being used for "echo "चौरेउत्तमयादव " | utf8-unicode" command

Comment: @Pangea: it is a homebrew C program.  If you'd like to obtain it, contact me - see my profile for my email address.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation where I had to display data something like this
"\U0928\U093e\U0936\U092a\U093e\U0924\U0940" which has to be नाशपाती

I search out a lot to convert it but the answer that I found out myself was very simple & easy.

Only I had to put the given string coming from JSON into UILabel or anything you want.
In my case, it was something like this:

```
let meaning = array[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
cell.textLabel?.text = meaning.value(forKey: "key") as? String
```